# Filter Multiple Conditions Array

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting

I am trying to filter every negative number as well as every other number on an array with MATLAB. How's this possible? I thought I could have done this but it is not working:

```
Z = A(A<0 | 2:2:end)
```

Comment: explain your question, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `2:2:end` simply returns the following array

```
[2, 4, 6, .... % All the way up to numel(A)
```

The conditional yields a `logical` array the size of `A` that is `true` where an element is negative and `false` otherwise.

You can't combine these two because they are two different types and two different sizes.

If you want all numbers that are *either* a negative number or occur at an even location you could create a logical array that is `true` at all of the even locations (and `false` otherwise) and then perform logical operations using that instead. To do this, we create an array from `[1....numel(A)]` and perform the modulo operation ([`mod`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html)) with 2. Even numbers will have a remainder of `0` and odd numbers will have a remained of `1`.  Therefore, by comparing the result of `mod(...,2)` to `0` (`== 0`) we get a logical array that is `true` in all of the even locations and `false` otherwise.

```
even_locations = mod(1:numel(A), 2) == 0;
Z = A(A < 0 | even_locations);
```

If you simply want the even locations that are *also* negative

```
tmp = A(2:2:end);
Z = tmp(tmp < 0);
```

Or you can use the `even_locations` array above:

```
Z = A(A < 0 & even_locations);
```

Comment: It works. Can you please explain me or give me where is the documentation for `mod(1:numel(A), 2) == 0`

Comment: @carlosremove I added more of a description